# Is it possible to count how many rows have an empty specified 'cell' or column in a csv?

Tags: php, csv, count

I have a changing csv file that looks something like the following. I am trying to find out how I can count how many jobs have not been completed yet (have an empty field)
CSV example:

```
id,job_name,started,completed,
1,project_1,17-07-20,20-07-20,
2,project_2,18-07-20,,
3,project_3,18-07-20,19-07-20,
4,project_4,19-08-20,,
5,project_5,20-07-20,,
```

In this example, I am looking to return '3'. (out of the 6 lines, 3 lines show row 4 as being empty)

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php

    $csv_complete_contents = array_map('str_getcsv', file('example.csv'));
    $csv_complete_filtered = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $csv_complete_contents));
    $csv_num_rows = count($csv_complete_filtered);

    echo $csv_num_rows;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done 2 versions of the code, the first one is based on what you already have, the second (IMHO) is a lot simpler.

Based on what you already have, the difference is that you currently filter on an entire row, so it will only count empty rows.  This uses `array_column()` to extract the 4th column and then filters that.  This also gives the number of filled rows, so I subtract it from the total rows...

```
$csv_complete_contents = array_map('str_getcsv', file('a.csv'));
$csv_complete_filtered = array_filter(array_column($csv_complete_contents, 3));
$csv_filled_rows = count($csv_complete_filtered);

echo count($csv_complete_contents) - $csv_filled_rows;
```

This uses a straight read CSV with `fopen()` and `fgetcsv()`. At each row it counts if the column is empty, this reduces the use of several `array_` functions and makes it so much easier to read...

```
$fh = fopen("a.csv", "r");
$empty = 0;
$data = [];
while ( $row = fgetcsv($fh) )   {
    $data[] = $row;
    if ( empty($row [3]) )  {
        $empty++;
    }
}

echo $empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code as:

```
$csv_complete_contents = array_map('str_getcsv', file('example.csv'));
$csv_complete_filtered = array_filter(
    $csv_complete_contents,
    function ($v) {
        // to see what value you get
        //print_r($v);  

        // if completed is not empty - we count it
        return !empty($v[3]);

        // if you need NOT completed:
        // return empty($v[3]);
    }
);
$csv_num_rows = count($csv_complete_filtered);

echo $csv_num_rows;
```